# How does accessing ivars directly differ from using an accessor?

Tags: objective-c

So in some of the codes I see, they access an objects ivar directly instead of using accessors .  What are the advantages of using them instead of accessors?

So how would this

```
thing = object->ivar
```

differ from this?

```
thing = object.ivar
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say, I totally loathe the Objective-C dot notation.  It sacrifices understandability for brevity and that is a bad thing.  In fact, the other two answers here both show evidence of the kind of confusion dot notation introduces.

Having got the rant out of the way, I'll now try to answer the question.

Under the hood, Objective-C objects are implemented as **pointers** to C structs.  This is why

```
obj->ivar
```

sometimes works.  Given that it's a C struct

(*obj).ivar

should also work exactly as you would expect for C.  Having said that, you can make ivars private or protected, in which case using the above outside a scope where they are visible will cause a compiler error.

The dot operator when applied to an Objective-C object (which is a pointer don't forget) has a totally different meaning.  It's syntactic sugar for sending an accessor message to the object meaning that:

```
foo = obj.property;
obj.property = foo;
```

is **identical** in effect to

```
foo = [obj property];
[obj setProperty: foo];
```

That is all there is to dot notation.  If you go through your code changing all instances of the first form to instances of the second form, you have done everything the compiler does wrt dot notation.

In particular

- you do not need a declared `@property` to use dot notation.  You can declare the set and get accessors in the traditional way as Objective C methods, although it is definitely best practice to use `@property` declarations for things that are logically properties.
- you do not need a backing instance variable.  There's no reason why your getters and setters can't calculate values.

Given the above, the major difference between `obj->ivar` and `obj.ivar` is that the former modifies the ivar directly and  latter invokes an accessor, this means that the latter can do any memory management stuff needed (retains, releases, copies etc) and can also invoke key value observing.

Answer (score 2):

This is one thing with a huge difference between c/c++ and objective-c.

In C/C++ the `.` accesses the variable directly and the `->` accesses the variable if it's a pointer to the variable, so basically it is the same.

In Objective-C the `.` is a shortcut to access the property using the setter and getter function and it is **always** using those functions. You can't access ivars with it if there is no property with that name.

Some say it's "dirty" to allow direct access to the variables. If more people work on the code it's "cleaner" to use accessors because it might be easier to debug where variables are changed since you can always break in the setter.

You can even do "bad" things with it, like:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray alloc] init];
int count = array.count;
array.release;
```

this will technically work, because the `array.release` is a shortcut for `[array release]` but it is bad style to use `.` for other things then properties.

Comment: -1: There are quite a few things wrong with this answer.  The worst is that the dot notation is independent of properties.  As long as the accessors exist, you can use it.  Also, since when is the count of elements of an array not a property of the array?

Comment: count is not a property of an array, maybe you should check it before downvoting? Properties is an Objective-C 2.0 feature, so It's just a function. You can check NSArray.h if you don't believe it. Also check http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Properties#Properties

Comment: @Bastian That's unexpected, but with the later introduction of properties it makes sense. count is a bit of a confusing example though, the release you added is clearer. Anyway, I'll remove my first comment, but I'll let the downvote remain until the bit "As far as I know you can't put everything in properties..." is removed or proven. To my knowledge, with correct usage of retain and assign, every type can be made into a property. At least structs can be properties (UIView's frame for example, a CGRect struct consisting of a CGPoint struct and a CGSize struct).

Comment: I don't think you can change your vote anymore, I think structs were a bad example .. I think the problems I encountered were c-style arrays like `CGPoint points[4]` as property but I'll remove that part from my answer since it has nothing directly to do with the question, anyways

Comment: @Bastian When an answer is edited, the lock on a downvote is removed. Took it off as promised! I'll even make it an upvote since I learned things from it.

Comment: @Bastian:  Of course count is a property.  It's not an `@property` but it could be.  **Logically**, it's a property.  I'll remove my down vote if you use `array.retain` as an example instead.

Comment: I change my code to make it more clear. But still technically it is not a property and as you can see in the google styleguide it's not ok (at least for them) to access it like an property.

Comment: @Bastian: Who cares about the Google style guide?  They are not the arbiters of truth.  I agree that you **should** declare properties with `@property` but NSArray's interface was written years before `@property` existed.  If you were writting it now and could mandate Objective-C 2.0, it's element count would be an `@property`.

Comment: @Bastian:  Actually, I don't know why I'm arguing.  I don't think dot notation should be used under any circumstances. Since your answer now uses release as a bad example, I have removed the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of properties is that they call methods that work with your ivars, in stead of calling the ivars directly, so you can do things like this:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if([self frameIsValid:frame])
    {
        if(self.flipsFrames)
        {
            frame.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.height,frame.size.width);
        }
        [super setFrame:frame];
        [delegate viewSubclass:self ChangedFrameTo:frame];
    }
}
```

Four advantages shown here are:

- The possibility to override
- The possibility to check a given value
- The possibility to alter a given value (use with caution)
- A way to react to calls

Another advantage:

```
-(NSInteger) amountOfMinutes
{
    return amountOfSeconds * 60;
}
```

You can use 1 ivar for multiple properties, saving memory and preventing/reducing redundancy, while keeping useful different formats.

There's not really an advantage to using ivars, except when you don't want to use a property so your class is more encapsulated. That does not make it impossible to reach, but it makes it clear it isn't supposed to be reached.

Answer (score -1):

All ivars are private. There is no way to access them directly from outside the object. Therefore, both of your code samples are equivalent, in ObjC terms.

When you call `object.ivar`, what you are really doing is calling `object`'s `ivar` selector. This may be either a getter method that you wrote yourself, or more likely, a synthesized getter method that you created with `@synthesize`.

`thing`, however, *is* an ivar. Your code would be calling the `ivar` selector on `object` and assigning the result directly to your instance's `thing` ivar.

If you had instead written it as `self.thing = object.ivar`, then you would be using your instance's setter method to assign to `thing`.

Some of the advantages of using accessors (specifically, synthesized properties) in ObjC are KVO/KVC compliance; better concurrency support; access control (readonly, readwrite); as well as all of the advantages that accessors give you in any other OO language.

Comment: nearly -1: ivars do not have to be private (see `@public` and `@protected`).